# Laravel REST structuring

Tags: php, laravel, rest

I am making a website which will have user login. Login form now leads to admin panel if your role is `admin` (route is behind `admin` middleware), and it leads back to home page if your role is `user`. Back on the home page you have the ability to see your profile page and add a product (which is behind `auth` middleware).

My question is what is the best approach to form my routes?

If I make `site.com/user/{id}` route, user ID's will be exposed to each user which logs in, as well as for example editing a product with `site.com/user/{id}/product/{product_id}`.

I see some security issues here and am wondering if a better solution is making `site.com/profile` route which will in turn in controller take `Auth::user()` not exposing ID's in the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your route without the ID and use `Auth::user()` It's best practice and makes your routes simpler

```
Public function profile(){
    $user = Auth::user();
    return view('profile', compact('user');
}
```

The above code is more straight forward than this:

```
Public function profile($id){
    $user = User::find($id);
    //prevent authenticated from viewing other users
    if($user == Auth::user()){
         return view('profile', compact('user');
    }else{
        //return something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about exposing user ID you can try use something like [hashids](https://github.com/vinkla/laravel-hashids), where ID will be encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

encode the `id` and `product_id` with `base64_encode()`

Example pass the `id` and `product_id` in url by encoding with `base64_encode()`
and when you want to use it use like this:

```
Route::get('user/{id}/product/{product_id}', function($code){
     $id = base64_decode($id);
     $product_id = base64_decode($product_id);
});
```

Comment: So how is using base64 a better solution for the OP's "security issue"?